# Handle Hardware events in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm newbie to ios development.Right now I would like to develop an security app for iPhone.

My requirements:

> 1) whenever we press the power off button we should get a login form
>   with email address and password fields.
>
> 2) if we enter wrong password
>   , then automatically camera should on(activate) and should able to
>   take the pictures of surroundings.
>
> 3)at the same time we have to track
>   the location

these are some of the requirements and all the photos ,location information should be sent to registered email address which we provide to enter while we download our application.

My question:
**How to track the hardware events such as power off button of iPhone , automatic camera on(activation)?**

Answer (score 0):

The Off button, even the home button is off limits. Apple has this sandbox principle that protects other apps from your app also protects IOS and other apps from your app, so a lot of what you ask for is not possible unless you are recoding IOS itself,

Having said that, you can build a lot of automatic things in your app like asking them to logon and so on and so forth, as what you described. You should be able to use the notification facility to periodically ask the user to take notice of the app but the user can choose to ignore the notification.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, whilst apps work in a sandbox mode and don't know about other applications on the device this isn't the reason why it would get rejected. There are 3 reasons why it would get rejected and all can be found if you review the [iOS App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html). These reasons would be (Not in any specific order)

> **2.6** - Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

It would get rejected because of **2.6** because the you will be required to read data from outside of the designated container in that you will need to see where the user is turning off/on.

> **2.5** - Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected

It would get rejected because of **2.5** because to access the on/off button you will be required to access a non-public API, so you will be using private APIs that developers outside of Apple aren't allowed to use.

> **10.5** - Apps that alter the functions of standard switches, such as the Volume Up/Down and Ring/Silent switches, will be rejected

And finally it would be rejected because of **10.5**  because you will be altering the user of the on/off buttons which isn't allowed.

There are probably more that it could be rejected because of but these will be the main 3.

Actually I would probably say it could possibly get rejected because of **4.3** as well but I'm not entirely sure on that one.

> **4.3** - Apps that use location-based APIs for emergency services will be rejected